# How to label rows/cols of a matrix of plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to make a matrix of plots where in each row/column I will plot the corresponding bar chart. Basically it looks like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,3)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        axarr[i,j].bar([1,2,3], [1,3,7])
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Now I'd also like to label the rows on the left and the columns on the top. Like a table where the column heading might be "a", "b", "c" and the rows might be "d", "e", "f".

Do you know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use/abuse the titles and ylabels or, if you're already using those, use `annotate` to place the text a fixed offset from the top/left of the axes.

As examples of both:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.bar(range(5), np.random.random(5), color=np.random.random((5,3)))

for ax, col in zip(axes[0,:], ['A', 'B', 'C']):
    ax.set_title(col, size=20)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], ['D', 'E', 'F']):
    ax.set_ylabel(row, size=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

And if we already have ylabels, etc, you can use annotate to place the row/column labels.  `annotate` is an easy way to allow the text to be places a fixed offset in points from the edge/center/etc of an axes (among many other things).  [See this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) (as well as several others) for more information on `annotate`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.bar(range(5), np.random.random(5), color=np.random.random((5,3)))
    ax.set(xlabel='X-axis', ylabel='Y-axis')

for ax, col in zip(axes[0,:], ['A', 'B', 'C']):
    ax.annotate(col, (0.5, 1), xytext=(0, 10), ha='center', va='bottom',
                size=20, xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points')

for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], ['D', 'E', 'F']):
    ax.annotate(row, (0, 0.5), xytext=(-45, 0), ha='right', va='center',
                size=20, rotation=90, xycoords='axes fraction',
                textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

(Side note on the -45 point offset for the row labels: We can calculate that if we need to, but for the moment I'm leaving it off and just fixing it for the matplotlib defaults.)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for the nice solutions and plots. I can learn new tricks from all the code :)